# Can't override default devise gem views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, view, rubygems

I want to use my devise generated views (with command `rails g devise:views users`) from `app/views/users`.

I already have set these options from `app/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.scoped_views = true
config.default_scope = :user
```

but it still uses default devise views from `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/devise-2.0.4/app/views/devise/`

So what should I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Are your views in `app/views/users` or `app/views/users/sessions`?

Comment: Tom L, [yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432946/cant-override-default-devise-gem-views#comment11927719_9432946)

Comment: Sorry, you responded while I changed my question since it was a dup of nash's.

Comment: Tom L, my app/views/users was generated with `rails g devise:views users` so it has identical stucture, nothing was changed, just generated

it there any way to point that devise should use my `app/views/users` directory?

Comment: What is your end goal, having a CRUD interface for users or modifying the login view?

Comment: Both, but firstly modifying login view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a custom login view, when you're using the default `User` devise resource, I think all you need is to create `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`. And, just for the moment, let's forget about the CRUD interface. And undo those `config/initializers/devise.rb` settings. Just see if you can get that working.

Comment: That combination works, but I can't understand why my is not working. I really need working scopes.

Comment: So that's working. Cool. If you want CRUD all you need is the usual controller and views. I don't think you need to mess around with scopes unless you have more than one kind of devise user.

Comment: To use scoped views for User you'll need to move the login view from `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` to `app/views/users/sessions/new.html.erb`.

Answer (score 10):

I was having this same problem and it took me forever to figure it out. Setting `config.scoped_views = true` is the first step, but there's another step that's not as clear.

If you look closely at some of the views that get generated by `rails g devise:views users` you'll see that the templates include `<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>` at the bottom of the file. Since you have generated these views, the shared links are now located in `users/shared/links`. Since devise doesn't find anything in `devise/shared/links` anymore, it uses the default links view instead.

Change `<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>` to `<%= render "users/shared/links" %>`and you're set!

Comment: That was the answer for me) Early there was no scope settings and devise has override default views by default.